# Laravel Composer Update Getting Error

Tags: php, laravel

After Successfully install laravel 5 When I try to update composer or install any laravel packages via composer getting this error

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are in the right folder when calling php artisan? Try to run the command `php artisan` only

Comment: After running that command 

`PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/an2/learn/izenik/bootstrapt/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/an2/learn/izenik/artisan on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/an2/learn/izenik/bootstrapt/app.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/an2/learn/izenik/artisan on line 20`

Comment: There was some file missing problem. Right now problem solved. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I'm glad that you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Artisan` file is missing. Download the [artisan](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan) file. If not work download [bootstrap](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/bootstrap) folder & replace into your bootstrap folder.

See: [How do I download a particular file from GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87954/how-do-i-download-a-particular-file-from-github)

Comment: Answer updated. Some of your files are missing that's sure.

Comment: Artisan file is exists in the root folder
`php artisan` command gives following error

`PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/an2/learn/izenik/bootstrapt/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/an2/learn/izenik/artisan on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/an2/learn/izenik/bootstrapt/app.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/an2/learn/izenik/artisan on line 20`

Comment: Replace [bootstrap](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/bootstrap) folder.

Comment: Thanks It's Works :)